# Search on an array

Tags: java

I need to print the searches of x numbers on an array. Right now, my program is always printing 50,000 for the number of searches. I know it prints 50,000 because I am calling NUMBER_SEARCHES directly, but I want it to print the actual number of searches. How can I fix/do that? Would I need to create a new variable? The very first line should look something like this: "It took 0.224 seconds to search ***990*** numbers on an array of size: 20000." My program right now searches 50,000 for every array.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ProgramSearches {
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 1000000;
    static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;
    static final int ARRAY_INCREMENT = 20000;
    static final int NUMBER_SEARCHES = 50000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        demoLinearSearchUnsorted();
        demoLinearSearchSorted();
        demoBinarySearchSelectionSort();
        demoBinarySearchFastSort();
    }
    public static void demoLinearSearchUnsorted() {
        System.out.println("testing Linear Search Unsorted");

        for (int i = ARRAY_INCREMENT; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i += ARRAY_INCREMENT) {
            int array[] = generateNumbers(i, MAX_VALUE);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_SEARCHES; j++) {
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE);
                boolean search = linearSearch(array, num);
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double seconds = (double) (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
            System.out.println("It took " + seconds + " seconds to search "
                    + NUMBER_SEARCHES + " numbers on an array of size: " + i);
        }
    }
    public static void demoLinearSearchSorted() {
        System.out.println("testing Linear Search Sorted");
        for (int i = ARRAY_INCREMENT; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i += ARRAY_INCREMENT) {
            int array[] = generateNumbers(i, MAX_VALUE);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            selectionSort(array);
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_SEARCHES; j++) {
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE);
                boolean search = linearSearch(array, num);
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double seconds = (double) (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
            System.out.println("It took " + seconds + " seconds to search "
                    + NUMBER_SEARCHES + " numbers on an array of size: " + i);
        }
    }
    public static void demoBinarySearchSelectionSort() {
        System.out.println("testing Binary Search using Selection Sort");
        for (int i = ARRAY_INCREMENT; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i += ARRAY_INCREMENT) {
            int array[] = generateNumbers(i, MAX_VALUE);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            selectionSort(array);
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_SEARCHES; j++) {
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE);
                boolean search = binarySearch(array, num);
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double seconds = (double) (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
            System.out.println("It took " + seconds + " seconds to search "
                    + NUMBER_SEARCHES + " numbers on an array of size: " + i);
        }
    }
    public static void demoBinarySearchFastSort() {
        System.out.println("testing Binary Search using built-in sort method");
        for (int i = ARRAY_INCREMENT; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i += ARRAY_INCREMENT) {
            int array[] = generateNumbers(i, MAX_VALUE);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(array);
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_SEARCHES; j++) {
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE);
                boolean search = binarySearch(array, num);
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double seconds = (double) (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
            System.out.println("It took " + seconds + " seconds to search "
                    + NUMBER_SEARCHES + " numbers on an array of size: " + i);
        }
    }
    public static int[] generateNumbers(int howMany, int maxValue) {
        if (howMany < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int array[] = new int[howMany];
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * maxValue);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static boolean linearSearch(int[] data, int search) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == search) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean binarySearch(int[] data, int search) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = data.length - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (data[mid] == search) {
                return true;
            } else if (data[mid] < search) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void selectionSort(int[] data) {
        int n = data.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int index_min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                if (data[j] < data[index_min])
                    index_min = j;
            int temp = data[index_min];
            data[index_min] = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? That's a lot of code, by the way, is all of it essential for this question? See: [mcve].

Comment: Question, in my answer I am looking for one number in an array (sorted or not) but re-reading your question, it seems like you have an array of numbers to find. Where are those numbers coming from?

Comment: Comment: when you name an array of integer simply as `array` it is hard for others to tell what the contents are for.  Variable names are useful if they describe what they contain instead of what they are.  I.e. `generatedNumbers` is better than `intArray` as it adds more readability to your code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a local variable on each method or globally if you want to reused it but be careful that other methods don't override it. And each time an iteration of the corresponding method occurs add +1 to the variable, at the end of the search it would get back the total number of searches.

something like:

```java
public void searchMethod(.. ..){
  int counter=0;
  for(.. .. ..){
     ...
     ...
     counter++;
  }
  System.out.println("This is the total number of searches: "+counter);
  //if variable is declared globally reset it after each method counter=0;
}
```

Comment: Would that work for a local variable? I am a bit confused, what would go inside the for loop in this case?

Comment: Inside the loop would go the search method that you are using. It works with a local variable but it has to be defined in each search method. Each iteration in your search method means a new "search", the less steps the more efficient is the search method.

Comment: It only adds +1 to the search. So now I am getting 50,001.

Comment: I guess you are using the variable called NUMBER_SEARCHES which is final, so, each time the counter tries to add +1 it produces 50,001 remove "final", try again, and make sure you are placing the counter in the right place. Each iteration means a new search.